# Kicad Clearance Rules not Applied

Tags: kicad

I'm doing a BGA design where I want a very small clearance between copper. I've set up my clearances as shown below, but for some reason the routing seems to completely ignore this and does not allow traces to be closer than 0.2mm apart. The only other place I can find clearance listed is the net class menu, so I changed the clearance value there to 0.1mm as well, but still no changes. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind zones, net classes, and footprints can have their own rules that will override this.

Comment: @evildemonic That will override this *if set higher*. A zone with its clearance set lower than these values will not override them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the two items you want to be closer than 0.2mm and use the menu "Inspect->Clearance Resolution" to find out why they won't get closer

[image: Clearance Resolution]

Comment: Thanks for the tool, I didn't know that existed. I'm still unsure what is preventing certain objects from getting closer. I've added the image to my original post- I'm, not sure how to attach it to the comment.

Comment: @RobertZukowski Be sure to click on the "Holes" tab to check hole-to-hole clearances.  It looks like you have that set to 0.25mm which would be my guess for the issue here